# Read and Write to Access using a HTML webpage

Tags: html, database, excel, ms-access

Im quite new to HTML. What I am trying to do, is create a table in HTML (Which I have done with the standard table tags (table)(/table) etc...

The table has a number of headings, such as Name, Number, 10/10, Percentage, Option

(those aren't the exact titles but you get the idea)

The Name and Number heading is just text that won't change (the same for the text beneath these columns) Which is all fine and dandy, very easy to do.

The part I am struggling with, is part of the table that needs to be able to be edited and saved. In a nutshell, what I want 2 of the columns to do:

When the webpage is loaded up, display information that is stored in `MS-Access` or `MS-Excel` (So Automatically READ from file on page loadup) 
When the user changes information on the webpage I want it to amend the data in the correct cells on the Access page, so overwrite it, As if you were typing something into Access yourself and clicking the save button.

Is this possible using HTML, Javascript and or PHP? Everything needs to be Clientside. The webpage is built, i'm Using Input type="text" for the text boxes in the table, and I was wondering if using (form) (/form) and some (Script) I could do this. I have searched on the internet and have found some examples where you can read and write to Excel but need ActiveX enabled on IE. It's a work computer and a task I have been asked to complete. There are no administrator privaliges on the system, and I can't enable ActiveX controls in IE so the other method did not work for me. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't archive things like file access, reading and writing to databases's **client side**. You need to use a server side technology, incidentally, PHP is a **server side** technology and not client side.

**Client side** is everything that is run on the users browser, I.E. Chrome, etc. **Server side** is everything that is run within the web server, before the HTML is sent to the client.

I get the feeling your trying to run before you can walk here. You need to research how web sites work more.